# Why does the function "everymonth" return the unexpected result?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, return-value

I defined the function `everymonth`. I want to use the function's return value. However,by the statement `int*p=everymonth(i);`,
I can not use the array `monthdays` as I intend.

At first, I thought that the scope of the array `monthdays` is wrong, so I
defined it as the global variable. But it is incorrect as well.

```
int * everymonth(int year)
{
    int monthdays[12]= {31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334,335}; 
    if(year%400==0 ||(year%4==0 && year%100!=0))
    {
        for(int i=1; i<12; i++)
        {
            monthdays[i]++;
        }
    }

    return q;
}
int main()
{
int sum=0;
int *p=everymonth(i);//i is a Constant 
for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
            {
                sum=sum+p[i];
                printf("%d\n",p[i]);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write what you intend to do.

Your function `everymonth` returns `q` without defining it. I assume you want to return `monthdays`, because otherwise it doesn't make sense to modify it before returning.

If you return `monthdays`, a local variable, that is definitely a problem. If you make `monthdays`, that problem is fixed for the first call to the function, but you have a problem after the first leap year.

Then in `main`, you calculate the sum of the sum of the days at the end of each month. So for February you would have `31+(31+28)' and so on.